# Cache data from HTTP request in RxJava

Tags: android, caching, rx-java, kotlin, race-condition

I have this FilmStore that fetch a film from a REST API.

```
class ApiFilmsStore(private val tmdApi: TmdApi, private val converter: ApiFilmToFilmConverter) : FilmsStore {

    override fun get(filmId: String): Observable<Film> {
        return tmdApi.filmById(filmId).flatMap { apiFilm -> Observable.just(converter.convert(apiFilm)) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }

}
```

I have this another one that is a decorator to return data from cache if exists:

```
class CacheableFilmsStore(private val origin: FilmsStore) : FilmsStore {

    private val cache = ReactiveCache<Film>()

    override fun get(filmId: String): Observable<Film> {
        return cache[filmId].onErrorResumeNext({
            origin[filmId].doOnNext { film ->
                cache.put(filmId, film)
            }
        })
    }

}
```

And I have this class ReactiveCache that manages the in-memory data:

```
class ReactiveCache<T> {

    private val cache = LruCache<String, T>(4 * 1024 * 1024) //4MiB

    operator fun get(key: String): Observable<T> {
        return Observable.create { subscriber ->
            //synchronized (this) { It doesn't work
                val value = cache[key]
                if (value == null) {
                    subscriber.onError(KeyNotExistsException())
                } else {
                    subscriber.onNext(value)
                    subscriber.onCompleted()
                }
             //}
        }
    }

    fun put(key: String, value: T) {
        cache.put(key, value)
    }

}
```

Problem is that there is a race condition. Two fragments retrieve the same film when app starts, and both are fetching the film from the API, because when the second is gonna get the film, it hasn't been put in cache, yet.

How could I synchronize that? I have tried to putting `synchronized`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: From the two fragments' perspectives, is `ReactiveCache`, or the `ApiFilmsStore` that uses it, used as a singleton (perhaps via a DI framework)? In other words, is it the same object? In other words, have you ruled out yet that you might have two separate caches?

Comment: (also, side note:   when you have this: `.flatMap { apiFilm -> Observable.just(converter.convert(apiFilm)) }` consider using `.map { apiFilm -> converter.convert(apiFilm) }`, or w/ lambda methods `.map(converter::convert)`)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, both fragments are using the same instance. I'm using a singleton CacheableFilmsStore with Dagger2. I have changed flatMap with map, nice point ;)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be for the cache to multicast.

There might be a better to do it, but here's a rough idea (please forgive the Java):

**CacheableFilmsStore:**

```
// A map since you'll likely want to separate this by key.
Map<String, Observable<T>> observableMap = new HashMap<>();

...get(...) {
    if (observableMap.containsKey(key)) { 
        return observableMap.get(key); 
    } else {
        Observable<T> observable = Observable.create(...)
            .publish()     // distributes results to all active subscribers
            .refCount();   // cleans up resources established by `publish()`
        observableMap.put(key, observable);
        return observable;
    }
}
```

Scenarios:

1. If the result for this key is not yet in your LruCache, then both fragments should end up listening to just one API call, not two.
2. If a subsequent fetch is made, then it will hit your cache straight away and be done.

When the source observable completes (and all subscribers receive their OnComplete), then `refCount` will cause the `ConnectableObservable` created by `publish()` to be *disconnected* and cleaned up - but note that it is still usable. The next time that Observable object (created by `refCount()`) is subscribed to, it will simply re-connect.